# Why does iptables not doing DNAT for the same subnet?

Tags: iptables, nat, dnat

I have the following NAT setup:

```
+--------------+       +-----------------------+     +-------------------+
|              |       |                       |     |                   |
|              |       |                       |     |                   |
|    PC 1      |       |    PC 2 (NAT)         |     |     PC 3          |
|  10.0.0.3    +-------+                       +-----+  10.0.0.4         |
|              |       |                       |     |  (NAT 172.24.4.2) |
|              |       |                       |     |                   |
+--------------+       +-----------------------+     +-------------------+
```

Whereas PC2 will do a NAT such that 10.0.0.4 will be translated to 172.24.4.2 during prerouting:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 172.24.4.2/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.4
```

When I try to ping from PC1 to PC3 with destination IP 172.24.4.2. Some how the packet is not doing any DNAT for me.

Here is what I capture on PC3:

```
10:15:41.017632 IP 10.0.0.3 > 172.24.4.2: ICMP echo request, id 8705, seq 0, length 64
```

It works fine if I change PC3 IP to a different subnet.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

> 10.0.0.4 will be translated to 172.24.4.2 during prerouting

The rule you have specified does exactly the opposite. It should translate the destination address `172.24.4.2` in the packet to `10.0.0.4`.

This is the capture you should see on the PC1-facing interface on PC2, because `tcpdump` shows the packets on the wire, before any processing by the TCP stack.

You should check the capture on PC3-facing interface. You also need to check the routing on PC2 so that the `172.24.4.2` address is routed correctly.

Comment: I am trying to ping 172.24.4.2 and the NAT box will have a route to 10.0.0.4. The purpose of this is that PC1 doesn't know 10.0.0.4 but 172.24.4.2 instead.